# Custom php ini on windows (Apache or IIS)

Tags: windows, apache, iis-7, php

i would like to make custom php ini using windows server 2008 x64 R2 , php 5.2.6 , iis 7 . apache 2.2, the problem is i cant custom php ini for each site , i found some articles on iis.net for customize iis and php but that wasn't helpful at all , so i switched to apache and found nothing too , if any found solution for this problem or any idea how to make this happen i would be thankful ,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With Apache, you can set php flags and values directly in VirtualHosts and .htaccess files like this:

```
php_admin_flag short_open_tag On
```

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php